# Styles does not apply to the button

Tags: css, sass

My problems are the small and medium version of the button. I want them to have smaller sizes than the main button with only `btn` class.

Please feel free to edit the code and give me an answer why classes `btn--med` and `btn--small` have no impact to the apperance of the button.

Here's the code :

```css
.btn {
  &:link,
  &:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #777;
    padding: 27px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
    min-width: 30rem;
    min-height: 8rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5rem;
  }
  &--small {
    max-width: 10rem;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  &--med {
    max-height: 5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Programista</a>
</div>
<div class="div-2">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--med">SCSS</a>
</div>
<div class="div-3">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--small">SCSS</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/maja5252/pen/gdrLvz?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `min-width` and `min-height` property used on `btn`. Change them:

```
.btn {
&:link,
&:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #777;
    padding: 27px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

&--small {
    max-width: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

&--med {
  max-height: 5rem;
}
}
```

min-height and min-width overrides the width and height if the decalred value is less than the one declared in min-width and min-height.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqybNa?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #777;
  padding: 27px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  min-width: 30rem;
  min-height: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  &:link,
  &:visited {
  }

  &.btn--small {
    min-width: 10rem;/*Change this value according to your needs*/
    min-height: 3rem;/*Change this value according to your needs*/
    background-color: blue;
  }

  &.btn--med {
    min-height: 5rem;/*Change this value according to your needs*/
     min-width: 15rem;/*Change this value according to your needs*/
  }
}
```

Replace `min-width` instead of `max-width` for small and medium buttons

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/gautamnaik1994/pen/QVNdNW?editors=0100)

Comment: This is great! But I don't understand how it works. When we have "&.btn--small" nested in ".btn" it should translate into ".btn.btn--small". Is it even correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
You should modify same properties for both btn--small and btn--med button class.

in your code for "btn--small" you are modifying its "max-width" property.
while for "btn--med" you are modifying "max-height" property. 
Modify same properties for both classes. 
for example 
&--small {
   max-width: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
 max-height: 5rem;
}

&--med {
  max-height: 5rem;
  max-width: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers you need to modify the same properties as well as the same pseudo classes. Since you're main button only touching `:link` and `:visited` your `--sm` and `--med` also need to be wrapped for `:link` and `:visited`

https://codepen.io/drGrove/pen/XPdpJN

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about it! But I think the code looks a bit messy now, compared to the other answers :)